# Convergence of maximum of iid random variables in distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, central-limit-theorem

> Given $X_i, i \geq 1$ iid random variables, with mean zero and variance one, I would like  to show that $$ M_n = \max_{1 \leq k \leq n}\left\{\frac{|X_k|}{\sqrt n}\right\} \xrightarrow{d} 0$$ as $n \to \infty$.

I know that $P(M_n \leq x) = \big(P(|X_1| \leq x \sqrt n)\big)^{n}$. However, as $n \to  \infty$, it may not be necessary that this goes to one for positive $x$.

I tried using Chebyshev's inequality after finding the distribution functions, but the factors coming from the variance and the scaling factor cancel out, so the right hand side is not meaningful there.

I would like to see if I can use characteristic functions to do this (find the characteristic function of $M_n$, and show that it goes to $1$ everywhere). But I was unable to proceed this way as well.

Comment: Did you try something like this : $E(|X_1|^2) = -\int_0^\infty x^2 dP(|X_1| > x)=\int_0^\infty 2x P(|X_1| > x)dx=\int_0^\infty 2 a t^{1/2} P(X_1 > a\sqrt{t})\frac{a\, dt}{\sqrt{t}}$.

That it converges, by comparison with $\int_1^{t_k} \frac{1}{t}dt$ implies there is a sequence $t_k \to \infty$ such that $t_k P(X_1 > a\sqrt{t_k}) \to 0$ and your claim follows from $1-(1-\epsilon)^n \sim n\epsilon$

Comment: I have seen the second equality, I tried playing around with it. How do you see the third one converging? I don't see how it compares with $\int \frac 1t dt$, since $\sqrt t$ on top and bottom cancel in that expression.

Comment: The variance converges that's in the assumption. What is the contradiction of there is a sequence $t_k \to \infty$ such that $t_k P(X_1 > a\sqrt{t_k}) \to 0$ ?

Comment: Ok, I see what you are saying. I will think for some time and get back to you.

Comment: Otherwise replace $\big(P(|X_1| \leq x \sqrt n)\big)^{n}$ by $\big(P(|X_1| \leq x n)\big)^{n^2}$ and use  $E(|X_1|^2) < \infty$ directly.

Comment: Does this still hold of the mean of $X_i$ is not zero? Or is it the same as with CLT?

Comment: @runr I don't think the fact that the variable was mean zero was used anywhere. Besides, if you translate by a constant (in this case, the mean), then the maximum also translates by the same constant, which is then being divided by $\sqrt n$, so that will just go to zero. So you can have variables of any mean. This is not a CLT result, mind you, more of an extreme value result, because this is saying that the maximum value of some iid random variables of bounded variance grows slower in distribution than the square root of the number of variables.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon thanks for the explanation. I'm working with a similar problem, trying to follow the accepted answer, but can't fully see where the assumptions are used. Say if variance would be $=n$ instead of 1, would it then follow that $1/n$ instead of $1/\sqrt{n}$ would be needed to converge to 0; meanwhile it would converge to some EVD with $n^{-1/2}$? I'm just guessing this based on Markov, but not really sure it's applicable directly.

Comment: @runr I see! The quantity $P(|X|^2 \leq \epsilon^2 n)$ is what should be attempt to be controlled. I will think more about this, but yeah, certainly the convergence to zero part should be correct, while the other part, I expect it to go through as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Note that 
$$ \begin{align}
P\left(\frac{\max_{1\leq i\leq n}|X_i|}{\sqrt n} > \epsilon  \right)&=
1-P\left(\max_{1\leq i\leq n}|X_i| \leq \epsilon \sqrt n  \right)\\
&= 1-P\left(|X_1| \leq \epsilon \sqrt n  \right)^n \\
&= 1-P\left(|X_1|^2 \leq \epsilon ^2 n  \right)^n
\end{align}$$

For any integrable $X$, $\lim_{x\to \infty} xP(X> x )=0$. Indeed $$\begin{align} xP(X> x ) = x\int \mathbb 1_{X> x}(w) dP(w) &\leq x\int \mathbb 1_{X> x}(w)\frac{X(w)}{x} dP(w)\\
&=\int \mathbb 1_{X> x}(w) X(w) dP(w)  \end{align}$$
and $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to \infty} \int \mathbb 1_{X> x}(w) X(w) dP(w)=0$ by dominated convergence.

Here, this implies $P\left(|X_1|^2 > \epsilon ^2 n  \right)=o\left( \frac{1}{n}\right)$, hence 
$$ \begin{align}
P\left(\frac{\max_{1\leq i\leq n}|X_i|}{\sqrt n} > \epsilon  \right)&=
1-\left(1+o\left( \frac{1}{n}\right)  \right)^n\\
&= 1-\exp\left(n\ln \left(1+o\left( \frac{1}{n}\right)  \right) \right)\\
&= 1-\exp\left(o\left( 1\right) \right)\\
&= o\left(1\right)
\end{align}$$

This proves convergence in probability to $0$, hence convergence in distribution to $0$.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the same. I knew it had to do with bounded variance, once the above comments came in.

Comment: great answer! I enjoyed. +1